# Init custom class UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Trying to init my custom class UIVIew with a xib file but crashed when trying to initialize properties :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ReportView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)

}

convenience init () {
    self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addBehavior()
}

func addBehavior (){
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 170/255, green: 170/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
    textView.layer.opacity = 0.9
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    textView.clipsToBounds = true
}
}
```

crashed on textview : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Did you connect the outlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible problems depending on how your xib looks like:

1. Either your outlet is not connected to the xib.
2. Or the outlet is not available during initialization, so you cannot access `textView` which is still `nil`. The correct approach then is to override `awakeFromNib` method and put `addBehavior` there.

Comment: didn't know the func awakeFromNib, learning everyday. Solved Thx !

Comment: @user3722523 By the way, the whole `addBehavior` setup, including the setup for layers can be set in Interface Builder (under `User Defined Runtime Attributes`) but if your goal is reusing that obviously your solution is better.